# Webpack loaders order

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-loader

I'm learning webpack .I've read about execution order of loaders.They are executed from right to left.And the result of one loader is passed to next loader,It's clear.But than I faced with such example:

```
{
  test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/,
  use: [
    'url-loader',
    'image-webpack-loader'
  ]
}
```

This example works.And it works when we change the order of loaders.I don't understand this moment.According to documentation the first loader should be 'image-webpack-loader' as it is placed at the very right.But in that case there should be error as this loader cannot work with images without url-loader.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, the order of the application of loaders is from right to left, that means with the array variation of `use` property it will start from the last item to the first one.

From `image-webpack-loader` [docs](https://github.com/tcoopman/image-webpack-loader#usage), you can see that it suppose to be the last, that means that it works on the images (minimize them) **before** url-loader saves them to file.

Probably the opposite combination won't work.

Comment: The opposite combination does works.I mentioned it.It is the question